# load menu from one site into another with header data

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created website (wordpress) and have a menu which i created with roles access etc. I want to use (jQuery Load) to retrieve the menu. This works fine (included code ive used below) but i need to fetch header data? i think i need to do this but could be wrong, as i want the user login data.

Basically the menu is setup using role access. As the user goes from website 1 (logged in) and goes to website 2 i want them to see the same menu and permissions. currently jquery load will just hide certain parts of the menu.

hope im making sense.

```js
$(function(){
var contentURI= '/intranet #menu-department-menu';
$('#tabs-1 #scroller').load('/php/loadexternalurl.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. You have a Wordpress page on server A. Then you have some other website on server B. Then you have a client C that has logged onto server A, then goes to server B and you want the PHP on server B to load the menu from server A.

This will not work, because while client C is logged into server A, server B is not. So for server A, the request coming from server B simply is not authenticated.

I also don't think you'll be able to fudge the headers, because if server A is set up correctly, its auth cookie must not be visible to javascript access, and even less so to access from a different host (server B).

**TL;DR:** If you can get this to work via javascript on the client, then this is a sign that your website security is... less than optimal.

(Even if "server A" and "server B" simply are two environments / applications running on the same machine, one does still not have access to the authentication status of clients of the other.)